# How to remove/reset window.onfocus function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

This has been driving me nuts.

When i load a page i initiate a window.onfocus function:

```
initializeFocusDetecttor: function () {
    window.onfocus = function () {
        var options = {
            useFade: false
        }

        $.OverWatch.worker.getView("/OverWatch/UpdateWatch", function () {

            $.OverWatch.init();
        }, options);
    }
}
```

However I don't want this behavior on every page but I don't know how to remove/reset this.

I have tried

```
window.onfocus = null;
window.onfocus = function(){return;};
window.onfocus = "";
```

but it does not work

Comment: if you change it to use jQuery event handling, you can just remove it (e.g. with `off` or `unbind`).

Comment: I know but I need to reset it by doing it like this. doing the updates this way solved another issue that I had

Comment: Sort out your other issue then. You should be able to use `on` and `off` (with a custom namespace so it will not interfere with other handlers). See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change it to use jQuery event handling, you can just remove it (e.g. with `off`).

```
initializeFocusDetecttor: function () {
    $(window).on('focus.mine', function () {
        var options = {
            useFade: false
        }

        $.OverWatch.worker.getView("/OverWatch/UpdateWatch", function () {

            $.OverWatch.init();
        }, options);
    });
});

// Some condition - turn it off
$(window).off('focus.mine');
```

This example adds the custom namespace `.mine` to the event name so that you can target it specifically without affecting other code using focus events.